# docker pull files from package.json

Tags: docker, github, npm

I have simple node.app, with this package.json:

```
{
  "name": "docker_web_app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Node.js on Docker",
  "author": "xxxxx",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.1",
    "myuser-deploy": "git+ssh://git@github.com:myuser/deploy.git"
  }
}
```

Normally when I run "**npm i**", it installs all dependencies, and also the one form the github. I have SSH that I previously setup with the github. All works fine so far.

Now I added Docker support for my application, like this

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:carbon

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm install --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  test-service:
    build: .
    image: test-service
    container_name: test-service
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    user: node
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '3001:3000'
```

When I run docker-compose up, it gives me this error:

```
> npm ERR! Error while executing: npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t
> ssh://git@github.com/myuser/deploy.git npm ERR!  npm ERR! Host key
> verification failed. npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote
> repository. npm ERR!  npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct
> access rights npm ERR! and the repository exists. npm ERR!  npm ERR!
> exited with error code: 128
> 
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

What can I do with the docker, so it uses my SSH keys?

Comment: Can you make sure that you have set proxy variables in docker-compose so that your container can communicate to the external world ?

Comment: I can confirm that. My docker can talk to the outside world. Since I pull other repositories (NPM) without problems.

Comment: If your pulling from a private git repo you will need to add your ssh key used for Github into the image.

Comment: pulling from a private git repo, you should either use ssh key or github token.